# VUE3 select dropdown filtering from an array/JSON

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuejs3

Vue newbie. Having an array of 5/6 items, and there is 3 select dropdown and based on filtering these select data need to display filter data. I showed with the button clicked and filtered data is displayed. Need to fix that all the select dropdown is filled and data will be displayed automatically. Required is in vue3. Live site link: https://64586b69338faa57d9529164--snazzy-lollipop-bbb7f7.netlify.app/

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <div>
      <label for="foodType">Food Type:</label>
      <v-select
        id="foodType"
        v-model="selectedFoodType"
        :options="foodTypes"
      ></v-select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="country">Country:</label>
      <v-select
        id="country"
        v-model="selectedCountry"
        :options="countries"
      ></v-select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="district">District:</label>
      <v-select
        id="district"
        v-model="selectedDistrict"
        :options="districts"
      ></v-select>
    </div>
    <button @click="displayData">Display Data</button>
    <ul v-if="displayUsers">
      <li v-for="user in filteredUsers" :key="user.id">
        <p>Name: {{ user.name }}</p>
        <p>Food Type: {{ user.foodType }}</p>
        <p>Country: {{ user.country }}</p>
        <p>District: {{ user.district }}</p>
        <p>projectName: {{ user.projectName }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

and Js is:

```
import vSelect from 'vue-select'
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';
export default {
  components: {
    vSelect
  },
  data() {
    return {
      users: [
        { id: 1, name: "Aluino", foodType: "Swales", country: "japan", district: "Bigender", projectName:"LineOne" },
        { id: 2, name: "Ella", foodType: "Guitton", country: "Panama", district: "Female",projectName:"LineOne" },
        { id: 3, name: "Julina", foodType: "Tarbard", country: "USA", district: "Female",projectName:"LineOne" },
        { id: 4, name: "Walden", foodType: "McPhilip", country: "Brazil", district: "Male",projectName:"LineOne" },
        { id: 5, name: "Hillary", foodType: "Billingsley", country: "Norway", district: "Male",projectName:"LineThree" },
        { id: 6, name: "KKK", foodType: "McPhilip", country: "Brazil", district: "JJJ",projectName:"LineOne" },
        { id: 7, name: "LLL", foodType: "Billingsley", country: "Norway", district: "Male",projectName:"LineThree" }
      ],
      selectedFoodType: null,
      selectedCountry: null,
      selectedDistrict: null,
      displayUsers: false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    foodTypes() {
      return Array.from(new Set(this.users.map(user => user.foodType)));
    },
    countries() {
      return Array.from(new Set(this.users.map(user => user.country)));
    },
    districts() {
      return Array.from(new Set(this.users.map(user => user.district)));
    },
    filteredUsers() {
      let filtered = this.users;
      if (this.selectedFoodType) {
        filtered = filtered.filter(user => user.foodType === this.selectedFoodType);
      }
      if (this.selectedCountry) {
        filtered = filtered.filter(user => user.country === this.selectedCountry);
      }
      if (this.selectedDistrict) {
        filtered = filtered.filter(user => user.district === this.selectedDistrict);
      }
      return filtered;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    displayData() {
      this.displayUsers = true;
      console.log(this.displayUsers)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood You correctly please take a look at following snippet:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  components: {
    vSelect: window["vue-select"]
  },
  data() {
    return {
      users: [{ id: 1, name: "Aluino", foodType: "Swales", country: "japan", district: "Bigender", projectName:"LineOne" }, { id: 2, name: "Ella", foodType: "Guitton", country: "Panama", district: "Female",projectName:"LineOne" }, { id: 3, name: "Julina", foodType: "Tarbard", country: "USA", district: "Female",projectName:"LineOne" }, { id: 4, name: "Walden", foodType: "Tarbard", country: "Brazil", district: "Male",projectName:"LineOne" }, { id: 5, name: "Hillary", foodType: "Billingsley", country: "Norway", district: "Male",projectName:"LineThree" }, { id: 6, name: "KKK", foodType: "McPhilip", country: "Brazil", district: "JJJ",projectName:"LineOne" }, { id: 7, name: "LLL", foodType: "Billingsley", country: "Norway", district: "Male",projectName:"LineThree" }],
      displayUsers: false,
      selects: [{name: 'foodType', title: 'Food Type:', model: null}, {name:'country', title: 'Country:', model: null}, {name:'district', title: 'District:', model: null}]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredUsers() {
      let filtered = this.users;
      const isselected = this.selects.filter(s => s.model)
      isselected.forEach(s => {
        filtered = filtered.filter(user => user[s.name] === this.selects[this.selects.findIndex(i => i.name === s.name)].model);
      })
      return filtered;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    seloptions(type) {
      return Array.from(new Set(this.users.map(user => user[type])));
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.displayUsers = true;
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@beta"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-select/dist/vue-select.css">
<div id="demo">
    <div>
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <div v-for="(sel, i) in selects" :key="i">
      <label :for="sel.name">{{ sel.title }}</label>
      <v-select
        :id="sel.name"
        v-model="sel.model"
        :options="seloptions(sel.name)"
      ></v-select>
    </div>
    <ul v-if="displayUsers">
      <li v-for="user in filteredUsers" :key="user.id">
        <p>Name: {{ user.name }}</p>
        <p>Food Type: {{ user.foodType }}</p>
        <p>Country: {{ user.country }}</p>
        <p>District: {{ user.district }}</p>
        <p>projectName: {{ user.projectName }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```